# How do I use ctypes to recv_into a C buffer multiple times?

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a Python library that is using `ctypes` to register a callback with a C library. The signature of the callback is:

```
CFUNCTYPE(c_int_32, c_uint_32, POINTER(c_byte), POINTER(c_size_t))
```

In this case, the third argument is a pointer to a byte array allocated by the C library, and the fourth argument is its length.

I would like to populate the byte array with data from the network by calling [`socket.recv_into`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv_into). More importantly, I would like to *completely fill* this byte array: that is, if `recv_into` returns fewer bytes than the fourth argument of this function then I'd like to call `recv_into` again.

Suppose my function looks like this:

```
def callback(first, second, buffer, size):
    total_read = 0
    while total_read < size[0]:
        total_read += some_socket.recv_into(buffer, size[0] - total_read)
        # XXX: What happens here???
```

My question is: how can I manipulate the value of `buffer` to ensure that each call to `recv_into` appends to the buffer, rather than overwriting previously-written data?

Comment: Following up to your comment on the other answer: does it work if you cast a slice of the buffer, and then doing the `recv_into`? Like `ctypes.cast(buffer[start:end], ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte))`. The downside is that you have to provide an end to the slice, or else the interpreter complains about the string being too large.

Comment: I don't think so. A slice of the buffer gives me a list of integers, which appears to have been copied out of the underlying buffer. That doesn't cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the comments, without intermediate casting:

```
# assuming we know OFFSET (where to start copying in the buffer)
# and AMOUNT (how many bytes we will read)
tmp_buf = (ctypes.c_char * size).from_address(ctypes.addressof(buffer.contents))
mview = memoryview(tmp_buf)[OFFSET:AMOUNT]
_ = sock.recv_into(mview, AMOUNT)
```

`buffer.contents` returns the pointer to the buffer, so its address can be extracted using `ctypes`

This worked for me in a simple C code that passes a pre-allocated buffer into a callback, that is registered in the python code.

Comment: This is pretty close to the answer I needed. I ended up reducing the amount of code by changing the callback so that it receives a `c_void_p` instead of `POINTER(c_byte)`, which means the first line can become `(ctypes.c_char *size).from_address(buffer)`. However, the rest of this code is exactly correct and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the trick is to wrap it into a memoryview:

```
>>> buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"fooxxx")
>>> sock.recv_into(memoryview(buf)[3:],3)  # receiving b"bar"
3
>>> buf.value
b'foobar'
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. To get a pointer like the one I have you have to do this: `buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'fooxxx'); ptr = ctypes.cast(buffer, ctypes.POINTER(c_byte))` and then operate on `ptr`. If you try that, you'll find you get an `IndexError` when you do this.

Comment: We solved @Lukasa's particular issue by changing `POINTER(c_byte)` to `POINTER(c_void_p)` and then using `(c_char * 1).from_address()`. For "normal" ctypes buffers, the answer above holds true.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code sample that shows how to have `recv_into` "append" into the buffer. Lots of boilerplate around setting up a socket but this allows you to run it immediatelly and see it in action.

```
import socket
import ctypes


_BUFFER_SIZE = 20
BufferType = ctypes.c_byte * _BUFFER_SIZE


if __name__ == '__main__':

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 10000))
    s.listen(1)
    c, _ = s.accept()

    buffer = BufferType()
    offset = 0
    available = _BUFFER_SIZE
    memview = memoryview(buffer)

    while offset < _BUFFER_SIZE:
        print('recv_into: offset=%r, available=%r' % (offset, available))
        count = c.recv_into(memview[offset:], available)
        offset += count
        available -= count

    print('done: buffer=%r' % (memview.tobytes(),))

    c.close()
    s.close()
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Nope: I don't want to create a new buffer object and allocate the memory for it. I'd like to tell ctypes to create a new buffer object from a pointer and size I already have, so that it doesn't allocate a new buffer but uses the one the C code provided for me.